# How to chose the best seeds in Europe?

Tags: seeds

I've watched a lot of youtube videos about gardening. I was paying particular attention to the plant and seed varieties. I noticed that a lot of seeds aren't sold in Europe. I don't know why that is, but I doubt there is any legal cause.

For example, I've heard wonderful things about tomato Boxcar Willie. When googled, I only found 1 europe based seller.

Is there a marketplace I am not aware of? How do you get seeds you heard of on the intrenet?

Comment: cmon Niall, it is a decent question

Comment: I assumed that countries around the world got internet and had the same stuff we are able to get.  I've learned people in India are unable to buy potting soil and Bamboo says that a lot of pesticides are banned in Europe (way cool).  Europe must also ban GMO seeds, a very good thing.  I get seeds from Territorial Seeds, NON GMO.  Not cheap.  Whatever seeds you chose, look for the words NON GMO, not organic or natural, NON GMO.  Try Park Seeds, they are a bigger outfit.  Bamboo is in England. Rewrite this question to ask 'How to chose the best seeds in England' something to that effect.

Comment: Seeds and plants can carry pathogens from one continent to another, see the Phylloxera case, one of the most famous pests of grapevines. That's why countries quarantine or forbid plant exchange. If you are in the E.U., you can buy seeds from member countries without a quarantine. Sellers usually prefer not to ship to other countries because of bureaucracy. If I were you, I would choose one of the cultivars available in E.U. and grow from that. If you are in a country that is not a member, but has a special trade agreement with the EU, you might have the same terms when buying from a EU member.

Comment: aa, tanks Alina. that makes sense.

Comment: Availability of seed is also limited due to the need to register a variety in order to sell it. I forget the exact details. Perhaps if the question were reworded to focus more on the limited availability rather than potential vendors it would be of more use.